# Disable the "Screen Off" button

Tags: javascript

If the tablet is connected to the keyboard, we want to disable/suppress the "Screen Off" button.

[image: screen of button]

I tried [keycode info](http://keycode.info/) , to get the key code but there is not keycode for screen off key .

keyboard name : viking keyboard

Comment: So... you want to disable the "Screen off" button so it won't work **at all in any** application with **JavaScript**?

Comment: I want to disable the screen off button just for my application.

Comment: I think this is like trying to disable the power button on Laptops that have their power button on the keyboard -- not possible because for applications, this button does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summary:
You can't disable it from javascript / using key code. There is no key code for the "Screen Off" key in Viking keyboard as it's a device specific key.

Longer version:
The keyboard you're referring to looks to be sold bundled with an android tablet called RCA Viking. It is most likely that the key would be recognized only by RCA Viking tablet - something similar to screen off Fn buttons you see in laptops. You'll not get a keycode for that as the key is device specific. It's also quite possible the key is connected only to the display on/off circuit directly with no connection to the CPU.